# Support of the pullback of a function

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $F: N → M$ be a $C^∞$ map of manifolds and $h: M → \mathbb R$ a $C^∞$ real-valued function. Prove that $supp F^*h \subset F^{-1}(supph)$.

I study the problem and I believe that first i need prove that $(F^*h)^{-1}({\mathbb R}^×) \subset F^{-1}(supp h)$ but i do not know how…

Comment: Write down the definition of support.

Comment: the support is the closer of the x in the manifold such that $f(x) $ is not zero

Comment: Right. So write down your two sets and use continuity of $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in\{p\in N:F^\ast h(p)\neq 0\}$ then $F^\ast h(x)\neq 0$, that is, $h(F(x))\neq 0.$ So $F(x)\in \{q\in M:h(q)\neq 0\}$, or $x\in F^{-1}(\{q\in M:h(q)\neq 0\}).$ That is, $\{p\in N:F^\ast h(p)\neq 0\}\subset F^{-1}(\{q\in M:h(q)\neq 0\}).$ Taking the closure, $\operatorname{supp} F^\ast h\subset\overline{F^{-1}(\{q\in M:h(q)\neq 0\})}$. Since $F$ is smooth and in particular continuous, we have $\overline{F^{-1}(\{q\in M:h(q)\neq 0\})}\subset F^{-1}(\operatorname{supp}h).$

Comment: Can you help check this @youler please.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514180/liouville-form-on-the-cotangent-bundle