# Liouville form on the cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

a) Let $(U,\phi) = (U,x^1,\dots,x^n)$ be a chart on a manifold $M$, and let
$(\pi^{-1}U,\tilde {\phi}) =(\pi^{-1}U,\tilde {x^1},\dots,\tilde {x^n},c_1,\dots,c_n)$ be the induced chart on the contangent bundle $T^*M$. Find a formula for the Liouville form $\lambda$ on $\pi^{-1}U$ in terms of the coordinates $\tilde {x^1},\dots,\tilde {x^n},c_1,\dots,c_n$

Proof:
Suppose $w_p = \sum c_i \, dx^i|_p$. Then
$$\lambda_{w_p}=\pi^*(w_p)=\sum_{}c_i(dx^i|_p)=\sum c_i(d\pi^*x^i)_{w_p}= \sum c_i(\pi^*dx^i)_{w_p} =\sum c_i(d\tilde {x^i})$$

Then $\lambda=\sum c_i \, dx^i$

Is it correct?

b) Prove that the Liouville form $\lambda$ on $T^*M$ is $C^\infty$.

For this i want use a) but i need help for this please.

Comment: What is the Liouville form?

Comment: Is defined in text An introduction to manifolds , L.Tu.

Comment: In the section 17, chapter 5

Comment: Someone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a)It's almost correct:

$$\lambda_{w_p}=\pi^*(w_p)=\pi^*\sum_{}c_i dx^i|_p=\sum c_i(\pi^*dx^i)_{w_p}= \sum c_i(d(\pi^*x^i))_{w_p} =\sum c_i(d\tilde{x^i})_{w_p}$$

hence in the coordinates of $T^*M$, where $w_p=(\tilde{x},c)$, you have $\lambda=\sum c_id\tilde{x^i}$. (Which many people write $\sum c_i dx_i$ using the natural identification.)

b) in coordinates, you see that $\lambda$ is a sum of smooth 1-forms, hence it is a smooth 1-form.